# SignalR client error windows app

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

I am getting this error on my windows client. The client actually waits for a bit and then calls back to the hub with a routine on the hub. Everything runs ok after I click "ok" on the pop up. Is there a property somewhere to change?

A possible deadlock detected. A callback registered with "HubProxy.On" or "Connection.Received" has been executing for at least 10 seconds.

Comment: Can you show some code? This error is just a heuristic - if you know that your callback may run for more than 10 seconds you can increase the timeout. See the commit message for more details: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/8b23a41100caee01c98c74f86790dd6d38e01e21

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Added this to the client when it creates the connection with the hub.

```
_hubConnection.DeadlockErrorTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);  //default is 10 seconds
```